# Number of tries required to have a 50% or better of winning

Tags: probability, gambling

I'm trying to set up "spin the fruit machine" for our summer fair. There will be $T$ tumblers, each with $N$ options. So the total number of possibilities is $T^N$. Ideally, I want the chances of winning to be reasonably good (it is just the company barbecue). Winning is defined as correctly guessing the result on each tumbler (ie. if there are 3 tumblers with 3 options on each, then ACB is a win but ACC or CBA is not).

The probability of winning is $1-[(T^N-1)/T^N]^Z$ where $Z$ is the number of tries. So all I do is find the $Z$ where this is >= 50%, right?

My initial arrangement of 3 tumblers with 5 options each appears to give the improbably large number of 169 goes required for each expected win. Oops... lots of unhappy punters at that rate! Looks like 2 tumblers with 4 options and about 10 goes required is about perfect.

Is my math right?

Comment: Everything is correct, except you wrote the "probability of not winning", where you meant to write "the probability of winning."

Comment: Ooh, well spotted, have now updated that. If its all correct (even if somewhat counter-intuitive) I guess there's no sense in me keeping this question alive...should I just delete it?

Comment: I suggest leaving it. It may be of use to future visitors.

Comment: Why not make more people somewhat happy by giving a smaller prize if you get a sufficiently large set of matching tumblers?

Comment: That way I could keep the "top" prize rather exclusive (eg. 3 tumblers with 5 options), but ensure there is a regular stream of winners for lesser prizes. Good thoughts, thanks.